# How to develop custom widgets in Microsoft Bot framework?

Tags: node.js, widget, botframework

I am working on Microsoft bot framework using Nodejs. I wanted to have a radio buttons and check boxes in my chatbot.

I have gone through the bot builder samples ([https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node][1]) provided by Microsoft. In the samples we have only cards, rich text, carousels, etc. I nowhere found details related to custom widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive cards is what you are looking for. You can create custom cards using it. Here is the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards) to the github project.

Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-an-adaptive-card) you can refer from Microsoft and these are some [samples](http://adaptivecards.io/samples/) of Adaptive cards.

This [Adaptive card](http://adaptivecards.io/samples/Inputs.html) contains radio buttons and check boxes.

As Nicolas R stated Adaptive cards are not fully supported in every channel. Here is the [compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots#channel-status) status.

Comment: I would add a disclaimer about the relative bad compatibility of Adaptive Cards accross channels for the moment. Be careful with those cards